# Can't get form based off mysql query to load all POST variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Trying to create form from a mysql query where I can update a field on each row. However it's only POSTing my last row.
Here is what I have.

```
    require('includes/application_top.php');
    if (!empty($_POST['inventory_daily-submit'])) {
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $id) {
    print_r($_POST);}
    }   ?>
    <form name="inventory_daily" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Product #</td>
    <td>Product Name</td>
    <td>Count Unit</td>
    <td>Begining Quantity</td>
    <td>Ending Quantity</td>
    <td>Unit Price</td>
    </tr>
    <input name="id[]" type="hidden" size="3" maxlength="3">
    <?php
    $inventory = $db->Execute('select product_id, product_name, quantity_on_hand, count_unit, case_price, unit_price, active, category_id from ' . TABLE_INVENTORY . ' WHERE active = 0 order by category_id ASC');
    while(!$inventory->EOF) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $inventory->fields['product_id']; ?><input name="product_id" type="hidden" size="3" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo $inventory->fields['product_id']; ?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo $inventory->fields['product_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $inventory->fields['count_unit']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $inventory->fields['quantity_on_hand']; ?>
        <input name="old_quantity" type="hidden" size="7" maxlength="7" value="<?php echo $inventory->fields['quantity_on_hand']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input name="<?php echo "new_quantity_on_hand"; ?>" type="text" size="7" maxlength="7"></td>
        <td><?php echo $inventory->fields['unit_price']; ?>
        <input name="unit_price" type="hidden" size="7" maxlength="7" value="<?php echo $inventory->fields['unit_price']; ?>">
        <input name="case_price" type="hidden" size="7" maxlength="7" value="<?php echo $inventory->fields['case_price']; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
  $inventory->MoveNext();
  }

?>
    </table>
<input type="submit" name="inventory_daily-submit">
</form>
```

Form displays 3 rows.

> 1 cheerwine each 33 ____  .38
>   2 cool blue each 11 ____  .66
>   3 diet peps each 13 ____  .51

Each row I enter new_quantity_on_hand with a number 1 less than `old_quantity`.
So I have 3 rows that should post with the numbers 32, 10 and 12 where the underscore is, but only the last row posts.

Output is:

```
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ) [product_id] => 3 [old_quantity] => 13.0 [new_quantity_on_hand] => 12 [unit_price] => 0.51 [case_price] => 12.25 [inventory_daily-submit] => Submit Query )
```

Comment: Your result (if for example you check the generated source code in the browser) will have three fields with identical names `new_quantity_on_hand`. If you POST that, only the last element will be submitted (each newer overwriting the one before). The same goes for `old_quantity`.
I generally suggest you take a look at the code that is generated. That might help you see where the rest is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!empty($_POST['product_id'])) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $i=0;
        $m=count($_POST['product_id']);
        echo $m; echo "<br>";
        while ($i < $m) {
        if(!empty($_POST['new_quantity_on_hand'][$i])){
    $old = $_POST['old_quantity'][$i];
    $new = $_POST['new_quantity_on_hand'][$i];

        $sql_data_array = array('product_id' => $_POST['product_id'][$i],
            'quantity_on_hand' => $_POST['new_quantity_on_hand'][$i],);

        }
        echo "Information has been successfully saved!<br>";
        }
        $i++;
        }

        }
```